# How to connect api with aouth2 and Authorization Code Grant Flow in Karete

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, authorization, token, karate

i want to test an api with karate but api has oauth2 and grant type is Authorization Code, Karate has a demo for oauth2 but its with grant type password but my api hasn't option password grant so can you help me how to connect api with authorization code in Karate?

demo:https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/oauth/oauth2.feature

Answer (score 0):

Please read the docs, forget about "grant" and "option" and all that.

All you need to do is create the proper header, and it depends on your particular API: https://github.com/intuit/karate#header

Talk to the team that manages the server if needed and find out how to get the token, it may be another API or a hard-coded value whatever.

Comment: hi, ok i see but i wonder the service I use is asking for user information over the browser for oauth2, how can I fill it in or what should I do to test it?

Comment: @AliKatırcıo using `form field` you can SIMULATE the submission of data from the browser. if that does not help, please assume that karate is the wrong tool for you and does not support what you want - so look for something else

Comment: thank for your helps, by the way, the browser is headless when i run scenario still can i manage this?

Comment: @AliKatırcıo you seem to be confused between API tests and UI tests. anyway, the answer to your question is that `form field` is for API tests, it has nothing to do with "headless"

Comment: no its not ui test, ok let me briefly explain the situation maybe it will be better. After entering the client information for the oauth2 type api, then when I say get access token, the application opens a browser to understand who I am and after the user information is entered, the token is received and the service is started to be used. This is the structure that works in postman now, and I am trying to turn it into api automation test with karate, but it is not a tool that I am very knowledgeable about. Thank you for your patience

Comment: @AliKatırcıo you need to understand what HTTP requests are being made by postman and the browser. if you can't do that, please give up on using karate